# Video codec for realtime on electronique board

Tags: video-streaming, real-time, codec, simd, neon

I had make some researches concerning video codecs. I found HEVC and VP9 as being biggest codecs nowadays. I use an electronique board which can capture video, and I want to carry this video on IP stream using wifi. In order to receive on mobile phone later, first in computeur would make me happy. All of that in "real time" (<0.2s).

But my question is : **which codec should I use on my electronique board** ?

knowing it's composed to:

```
- CPU Cortex A9 at 800MHz (X2)
- 1Go RAM
```

Whithout forget the [NEON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Advanced_SIMD_.28NEON.29) in CPUs.

*PS: I use linux, ffmpeg & VLC*

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

HEVC and VP9 and NOT the biggest codecs. They are the most talked about, but nobody uses them because they are very impractical. AVC is by far the 'biggest' (most used) codec. But even that may be difficult to pull off on your limited CPU. Try starting with x264 ultrafast.

Comment: [this comparison](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/200925/files/article-vp9-submited-v2.pdf)  and [this](http://iphome.hhi.de/marpe/download/Comp_LD_HEVC_VP9_X264_SPIE_2014-preprint.pdf) demonstrate that HEVC>VP9>AVC

Comment: Except very few browsers or phone can play back HEVC or VP9. And the CPU Required to encode it is 10x 264. So if greater then means more  expensive and unplayable. Yes it's greater.